# WYSIWYG Editor not registering update

Tags: javascript, angular, wysiwyg

I am building my own custom WYSIWYG text editor in Angular using a content editable div. I am extracting it as a component. I want to be able to type some text and format it and then when I click a button from the parent component it should either change the text in the editor or update it.

My parent component looks as follows:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-parent',
  templateUrl: `
    <form [formGroup]="form">
        <app-default-editor
        formControlName="body" >
        </app-default-editor>
    </form>

    <button (click)="changeValue()">Change Value</button>
    <p *ngIf="!form.valid">Counter is invalid!</p>

    <pre>{{ form.value | json }}</pre>
  `
})
export class ParentComponent  {

  initialText = '<H1>This is the heading</H1>';

  form = this.fb.group({
    body: '<H1>This is the heading</H1>'
  });

  changeValue(){
    this.form.patchValue({ body: 'This is my new text' });
  }

}
```

My editor component looks as follows:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-parent',
  templateUrl: `
    <button (click)="executeCommand('bold')" ><i class="fas fa-bold"></i></button>
    <button (click)="executeCommand('italic')" ><i class="fas fa-italic"></i></button>
    <button (click)="executeCommand('underline')" ><i class="fas fa-underline"></i></button>

    <div 
        #htmlEditor 
        id="htmlEditor" 
        contenteditable="true" 
        (input)="onTextChanged()" 
        [innerHTML]="initialText">
    </div>
  `
})
export class EditorComponent implements ControlValueAccessor, OnChanges {

    @Input()
    initialText = "";
    @Input()
    _textValue = "";
    @Input()
    minValue = 0;


    @ViewChild('htmlEditor') htmlEditor;


    ngAfterViewInit() {
        this.htmlEditor.nativeElement.innerHTML = this.initialText;
    }

    get textValue() {
        return this._textValue;
    }

    set textValue(val) {
        this._textValue = val;
        this.propagateChange(this._textValue);
    }

    writeValue(value: any) {
        if (value !== undefined) {
            this.textValue = value;
        }
    }

    propagateChange = (_: any) => { };

    registerOnChange(fn) {
        this.propagateChange = fn;
    }

    registerOnTouched() { }

    validateFn: Function;

    ngOnChanges(changes) {
        this.validateFn = createEditorRequiredValidator();
    }

    onTextChanged() {
        this.textValue = this.htmlEditor.nativeElement.innerHTML;
    }

    executeCommand(cmd) {
        document.execCommand(cmd, false, this.htmlEditor.nativeElement);
    }

}


export function createEditorRequiredValidator() {
    return function validateEditor(c: FormControl) {
        let err = {
            requiredError: {
                given: c.value,
                required: true
            }
        };

        return (c.value.length == 0) ? err : null;
    }
}
```

With the current code, I can format text to be bold, italic etc and the form in the parent component can display the value in the  tags. When I click the button to change the text to a predefined value the form updates but the editor doesn't show any changes.

Answer (score 1):

There are two little mistakes that prevent your code from working as it should.

**1. No provider for `NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR`**

This one should have given you errors in your console. To make sure you can use formControlName directive the component needs to provide a value accessor. You achive that by adding the providers when defining the editor component. Like this:

```
providers: [
  { provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR, useExisting: forwardRef(() => EditorComponent), multi: true}
]
```

When you did this the `writeValue` function within your editor component is called everytime the form control for the field body changes. Lets go to little mistake number two...

**2. innerHtml bound to initialText**

You update the text property within `writeValue` but that property is never bound to the template. The `innerHtml` binding only looks for the initialText property -  and that hasn´t changed.

Change your binding to look like this:

```
<div #htmlEditor 
     id="htmlEditor" 
     contenteditable="true" 
     (input)="onTextChanged()" 
     [innerHTML]="textValue">
```

You can utilize the initial text within the getter and return it in case of an empty text value.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up changing the changeValue method in the parent component to:

```
changeValue(){
    this.form.patchValue({ body: [WHATEVER THE TEXT MUST BE] });
    this.initialText = [WHATEVER THE TEXT MUST BE]
}
```

This seems to work but I don't think it is the best answer.